# jQuery alert / scrollTop not working in Opera or IE7

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-7

Wondering why I get this alert to work in Firefox and Safari but not Opera or IE... any insight much appreciated!

```
    $().scroll(function() {
    var scrolledpx = parseInt($().scrollTop());  

    if (scrolledpx < 375) {
        alert('true');
    }
});
```

Comment: Well if you arent actually using a selector that could be part of the issue :-)

Comment: I was going to say that but assumed it was just for his example lol

Comment: Try making it: $(document).scrollTop();

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolledpx = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());  

    if (scrolledpx < 375) {
        alert('true');
    }
});
```